# How can I solve "unable to prepare context: path "." not found" docker build's error?

Tags: docker, centos, centos7

I am trying to build Docker image from my Dockerfile. I have Docker-CE 18.06 installed on CentOS 7 guest OS, running on VMWare Player 14. The project directory is inside shared folder mounted via VMWare's vmhgfs-fuse tool. My host OS is Windows 10 Home. As of now, I don't use docker-compose for this project yet.

> [superdurszlak@localhost candidate-match]$ sudo docker build -t candidate-match .
>
> unable to prepare context: path "." not found
>
> [superdurszlak@localhost candidate-match]$ sudo docker build -t candidate-match --file ./Dockerfile .
>
> unable to prepare context: path "." not found

I have double-checked if my Dockerfile is named correctly, if my docker daemon is up and running, if my working directory is correct and if shared folder's contents are accessible from inside guest OS without issues.

What are possible causes of such an error?

Answer (score 2):

I'm in an Ubuntu environment and the snap was giving me this problem. I solved my issue by uninstalling and then installing with these directions: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

This is a permission problem. If the root user does not have access to read your current directory, and you run docker commands with `sudo`, then you will see the "not found" error. This likely indicates that a parent directory has no read and execute permissions in the last section (e.g. `chmod 700 $HOME` would break root access to `$HOME/my_proj`).

Two solutions:

1. As you've seen, run the commands as your own user instead of root. This is done by adding yourself to the docker group: `sudo usermod -aG docker $(id -un) && newgrp docker`
2. Fix the permissions on the parent directories using `chmod` to be at least `0755`. Make sure any sensitive files within these directories are appropriately limited (e.g. `0600`).

Comment: the issue for me was my user `umask` was wrong. took three steps to fix: (1.) i fixed all parent directories with `chmod 0755 dir_name` (2.) then i made sure to update my bashrc and cshrc to have `umask 002` (3.) then i did a fresh git clone so that all the created files had the correct file permission (from `umask 002`). then everything worked fine.

Comment: i use wsl in windows, is there anyway to resolve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the solution to said problem is straightforward yet possibly not obvious to inexperienced Docker users. I needed to add my user to group *docker* in order to build docker image from Dockerfile placed inside shared folder.

Interestingly enough, I can now build my docker image as a user without root privileges:

> [superdurszlak@localhost candidate-match]$ docker build .
>
> Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.055MB
>
> Step 1/8 : FROM ubuntu:18.04
>
> *works fine*

But running *sudo docker build ...* still causes error mentioned in the question.

According to docker docs, adding user to *docker* group is optional, though:
https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/

Answer (score 0):

The process worked for me is,

1. Make sure user is added to the docker group,

To check,

> cat /etc/group | grep docker

If not added, To add,

> sudo usermod -aG docker $(id -un) && newgrp docker

Adding user to docker group is optional, though:

> https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/

2. 'cd' into the folder where you have the Dockerfile. Make sure you can able to run below command, considering the filename is 'Dockerfile'

> cat Dockerfile

3. Make sure you can able to run docker commands without sudo,

> docker version

4. If above one is success. Then run the below command,

> docker build . -t candidate-match

Answer (score -1):

try this:

> sudo docker build . -t candidate-match

Comment: Your answer does not fix the problem. Your command and the command used in the question are interchangeable

Comment: i mean use the command without '.'